# the type exists in both asp.net

Tags: blogengine.net

I just integreated blogengine.net into my exting webapplication(not a website)

To do this I have converted all blog engine pages into webapplication page. set namespace references according to the application folders

I have built solution successfully.But when I run main application following error occured.

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'MyStore.App_Code.Controls.PostPager' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6332283b\32bb0d6a\App_Code.afjt0bia.dll' and 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6332283b\32bb0d6a\assembly\dl3\faca6d87\a3e83425_6ad8cd01\MyStore.DLL'
```

I have checked all the namespace refferences but I haven't found any duplicate refferences.

please help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code files out of the `App_Code` folder and put them in a `Classes` folder.